# How to activate debugging on server-side in ASP.NET MVC or ASPNET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging

I was coding on my machine and now I deployed the asp.net mvc application (on 3w DOT acidh-rdc DOT org)
So, locally it was showing me errors in controllers, if any! (FILE and LINE, etc.) But, online it doesn't show anything, it only returns the 500http code instead of showing me what has generated that error. 
Can someone tell me which directive I have to set in my config file ?
not the

```
<customError mode="Off|On|RemoteOnly">
```

because it redirects me to an error page. I wish i could see the debugging infos(LINE, FILE, etc.) if I can say so!

how to allow it online debbug in asp.net and secondly in asp.net MVC ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

u can any error that is nt being cought anywhere else in 
global.asax
`Application_Error()` method
then u can write it some where in the logs or just handle and send a custom error html string that u plan to do.

Comment: thank you for this answer, but last time we were able to see all debug information. for example, if you've forgotten a ";" or a syntaxe error... Someone has changed this directive accidentally and It's no longer available. 
'DO YOU HAVE A WEB.CONFIG FILE' SOLUTION ?

Comment: That wouldn't have compiled in the first place. Re-examine it on your dev machine.

Comment: that shud work fine to my knoledge.. do u by any change hav added any filter to handle the errors like.. filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

Comment: I say this because the error is asumed to be caught online. It's  connectionString problem, i mean!
locally it works well but after deploying, it returns an error: maybe you understand me*

Comment: just guessing.. hav u by any means added some new module to local iis and forgot to add it on the production enviornmnt..

Comment: The probleme was sold by the host. Arvixe has somewhere where you can check the option `Show Debug Symbols and Error`